# Do-while loop won't stop at the condition, also the negative function won't count the negative integers properly

Tags: c++

```
int numberInput;
int userInput;
int evens = 0;
int odds = 0;
int zeros = 0;
int positives = 0;
int negatives = 0;



cout<<"How many numbers are you going to enter? ";
cin>> numberInput;
cout << endl; 

do
{
    cout << "Enter data: ";
    cin >> userInput;

    cout << endl;

    {
    if (userInput>0) {
       positives++;}
    else {
        negatives++;}
    if (userInput==0){
        zeros++;}
    else if (userInput % 2==0){
        evens++;}
    else{
        odds++;}
    }

}
while (userInput<numberInput);

cout<<"Odd numbers entered: "<<odds<<endl;

cout<<"Even numbers entered: "<<evens<<endl;

cout<<"Positive integers: "<<positives<<endl;

cout<<"Negative integers: "<<negatives<<endl;

cout<<"Zero integers: "<<zeros<<endl;


        cout << "\nWould you like to input another set?";
    cout << "\nIf YES press <y> and if NO press <n>: ";
    char trial1;
    cin >> trial1;
    if(trial1 == 'y')
        main();
    else
    {
        cout << "\n-The program will now end-\n";
        cout << "\n-Thank you for using the program-\n\n\n\n";
     }  
     return 0;
        }
```

Hello, I would really like some help knowing what is the problem with my code, as I start in the output screen it asks me how many integers do I want and I typed 5, but then in entering data, it doesn't stop at 5. Also, it won't properly and accurately count the negative numbers.

Comment: Probably unrelated: [Thou shalt not call `main`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3). `main` is a special function that's allowed to do some really weird program-setup stuff that you really don't want to run twice.

Comment: You're comparing the user's input to the number of inputs you expect. That is, if you enter 5 first, the loop will stop when you enter a number greater than or equal to 5, not when you have entered five numbers.

Comment: And calling `main` has undefined behaviour. You know about loops - use one.

Comment: And you're counting zero as a negative number. Zero is neither positive nor negative. (It usually is considered even, though.)

Comment: If you know the number of iterations, a for loop is the better tasting syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Your `do-while` loop is comparing the user's data input to the number of iterations requested, rather than keeping track of how many iterations have actually been performed.

Also, you are trying to call `main()` directly, which is illegal.  Use another loop instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int numberInput;
    int userInput;
    int evens;
    int odds;
    int zeros;
    int positives;
    int negatives;
    char choice;

    do
    {
        cout << "How many numbers are you going to enter? ";
        cin >> numberInput;
        cout << endl; 

        evens = 0;
        odds = 0;
        zeros = 0;
        positives = 0;
        negatives = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numberInput; ++i)
        {
            cout << "Enter data: ";
            cin >> userInput;
            cout << endl;

            if (userInput % 2 == 0){
                ++evens;
            }
            else{
                ++odds;
            }

            if (userInput == 0){
                ++zeros;
            }
            else if (userInput > 0) {
                ++positives;
            }
            else {
                ++negatives;
            }
        }

        cout << "Odd numbers entered: " << odds << endl;
        cout << "Even numbers entered: " << evens << endl;
        cout << "Positive integers: " << positives << endl;
        cout << "Negative integers: " << negatives << endl;
        cout << "Zero integers: " << zeros << endl;

        cout << "\nWould you like to input another set?";
        cout << "\nIf YES press <y> and if NO press <n>: ";

        cin >> choice;
    }
    while (choice == 'y');

    cout << "\n-The program will now end-\n";
    cout << "\n-Thank you for using the program-\n\n\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! it has now pretty much solved my problem.